# regex to duplicate a word and add in extra text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a long list of words that I want to duplicate

Example

```
CallDateTime
WebDateTime
WavName
Dnis
Verified
Concern
ConcernCode
```

I'm trying to understand some regex to copy each word and placing to the right, along with adding in some needed text

```
's/(\t+)_(\w+)/\u\2, \u\1, \0/'
```

Well.. that is not working ,  **THIS IS EXPECTED OUTPUT NEEDED**

```
@CallDateTime = i.CallDateTime,
@WebDateTime = i.WebDateTime,
```

etc...

Obviously adding in  ^  with @  is easy and  $ with ,   , but I want to also copy with a regex

I have seen this

```
 ((\w+)_(\w+))
Replace Pattern:
\3, \2, \1
```

But I don't understand that ..

Comment: Add an example of the expected result.

Comment: Please update your tags to reflect the language you are using. Adding an example for expected output would also be helpful.

Comment: @CallDateTime = i.CallDateTime,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's solve this with notepad++:

Find what: `(\w+)`
Replace with: `@\1 = i.\1,`

Explanation:

- `\w+` matches one or more word characters
- `(...)` is a capturing group. You can reference it with `\1` in the replacement part
- replacement: A literal `@`, then the captured word, then a space, etc...

Comment: It's not about being smart. I've just spent much time with fiddling with regexes..

Comment: No need to use a capturing group here. Replace `\w+` with `@$0 = i.$0,` where `$0` stands for the whole match.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I explained with bullet point #2: *`(...)` is a capturing group. You can reference it with `\1` in the replacement part*

Answer (score 2):

Searching for `.+` and replacing it with `@$0 = i.$0,` should do the job.

https://regex101.com/r/WQXFy6/3

Answer (score 2):

Replace :
`\b(\w+)\b`
by
`@\1 = i.\1`
Javascript code :

```js
var str = "CallDateTime\nWebDateTime\nWavName\nDnis\nVerified\nConcern\nConcernCode";
str = str.replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, '@$1 = i.$1');
console.log(str);
```